# JSON iterator class

Tags: python, oop, iterator

I'm trying to create a custom iterator class to run through a JSON file of user data.

```
class trainUsers():
    def __getitem__(self, num):
        with open(file.json') as f:
            #if num > 43873:
             #   raise IndexError("end of file")
            train_user = [json.loads(line) for line in f]
        return train_user[num]
    def rating(self,num):
        return self[num]['rating']
    def id(self,num):
        return self[num]['user_id']
```

I can then access each user by

```
trainuser = data.trainUsers()

trainuser[num] #returns a dict
trainuser.rating(num)
```

However, I am running into a problem iterating.

```
count = 0
rating = 0
for i in trainuser:
    rating += trainuser.rating(i)
    count += 1
print stars/ count
```

the IndexError is commented out because it is always being called, and I thought the docs say the for loop needs the IndexError to function. the above gives the below error from the **getitem** function.

```
@return train_user[num]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not dict
```

I get that trainuser is returning a dictionary, but I can't conceptualize why the for loop is using the dictionary to iterate.

How can I make this class both iterate and call each dictionary individually?

Answer (score 0):

This is because your 'for' loop is returning each item from the json file as 'i' instead of the for loops index.

An example of a 'for' loop in python

```
>>> arr = ['hip','hello','hey']
>>> for i in arr:
>>>    print i
hip
hello
hey
```

In your case this should work:

```
>>> rating = 0
>>> for i in trainuser:
>>>     rating += trainuser['rating']
>>>
>>> print stars/ len(trainuser)
```

Or if you'd rather keep your method of finding the row in the json file by the index you can use enumerate:

```
>>> rating = 0
>>> for index, i in enumerate(trainuser):
>>>     rating += trainuser.rating(index)
>>>
>>> print stars/ len(trainuser)
```

Comment: hm. the first example doesn't work since my syntax is trainuser[index]['rating']. the second one is working, but it iterates a lot slower than opening the file directly in my code.  Good catch on my for loop, as I didn't see that at all.  I'm thinking I will need to map each line to speed things up, or I'll just hard code the open file in the for loop. Thanks.